# Interference between electromagnetic waves - conditions

Tags: optics, waves, education, interference

What are the conditions which ensure interference between electromagnetic waves? Is it sufficient that the two waves have the same wavelength before the scattering?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only condition for two waves to interfere is that they occupy the same point in space and in time. In fact, waves actually are electromagnetic fields and their values, when they interfere, are summed.